AWS S3 AccessDenied error when trying to download file from NASA EarthData
I'm trying to download a file from NASA EarthData's S3 bucket using temporary credentials provided through their system. However, I'm encountering an AccessDenied error when attempting to list objects in the bucket. I've modified my approach to target a specific file, but I'm still facing permission issues.
Here's the Python script I'm using:
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import os

BUCKET_NAME = "prod-lads"
OBJECT_KEY = "VNP46A2/VNP46A2.A2024237.h18v03.001.2024245102633.h5"
LOCAL_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), OBJECT_KEY.split('/')[-1])

# Credentials got on AWS S3 Access tab (see screenshot below)
AWS_CREDENTIALS = {
    "accessKeyId": "temporary_accessKeyId",
    "secretAccessKey": "temporary_secretAccessKey",
    "sessionToken": "temporary_sessionToken",
    "expiration": "temporary_expiration"
}

def create_s3_client(credentials):
    return boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials["accessKeyId"],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials["secretAccessKey"],
        aws_session_token=credentials["sessionToken"]
    )

def download_object(bucket_name, object_key, local_path, s3_client):
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket_name, object_key, local_path)
        print(f"Successfully downloaded {object_key} to {local_path}")
    except ClientError as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while downloading {object_key}: {e}")

def main():
    s3_client = create_s3_client(AWS_CREDENTIALS)
    download_object(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_KEY, LOCAL_PATH, s3_client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


When I run this script, I get the following error:
An error occurred while listing objects: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: User: arn:aws:sts::742459729046:assumed-role/s3-same-region-access-role/manonjacquin is not authorized to perform: s3:ListBucket on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::prod-lads" because no identity-based policy allows the s3:ListBucket action
However, even when I try to download a specific file without listing objects, I still encounter permission issues.

Specific Data I am trying to get:  https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C1897815356-LAADS&pg[0][v]=f&pg[0][gsk]=-start_date&sb[0]=3.09375%2C50.71252%2C7.80469%2C54.01901&fi=VIIRS&tl=1725268899!3!!&lat=52.30832049031109&long=-1.546875&zoom=5
What could be causing this? Is there something wrong with my AWS credentials or permissions? Are there any specific settings or configurations I need to check in my NASA EarthData account?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Found this, might help: NASA Earthdata Cloud Data Access Guide | National Snow and Ice Data Center
